# How to use shell expr to count the number of files under a directory

Tags: linux, shell

I want to count the number of files under a directory using

```
if [ `expr ls -l $data_dir/*_1.data | wc -l`  == 1 ]
then
     #blabla
fi
```

But bash kept poping syntax error.
Did I miss sth?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use `==` for integer comparisons. Use `-eq`.

Comment: `expr` does not take a command to execute as its argument. The easiest fix for the syntax error is to drop `expr` completely, but as others have pointed out, that's still not a very good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With normal shells:

```
if [ "$(exec find "$data_dir" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*_1.data' | wc -l)" -eq 1 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

With Bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
FILES=("$data_dir"/*_1.data)
if [[ ${#FILES[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: The first one will return the wrong result if you have file names with newlines because `wc -l` counts lines. An easy fix is to have `find` print e.g. the inode number instead of the file name. Look at the format string documentation for the `-printf` predicate.

Comment: What's with the `exec`?

Comment: @triplee Prevent unnecessary fork. It's a konsolebox style :)

Comment: No, you don't prevent any fork. Please, check the bash source code yourself, espacially the implementation of command substituion is `subst.c` and how the `make_child` function is implemented in `jobs.c`. Your exec is not wrong (so don't hurt), but doesn't prevent anything. ;)

Comment: @jm666 You're correct. I think I already realized the difference back then and stopped the practice but then I forgot it again :) So this is actually the cause of the odd feeling why I doubted using exec in `$()`. And by difference I mean it always does fork in process substitution unless you do `exec`.

Comment: See [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-how-to-discard-unwanted-stdin-815614/#post4011133). On my practice I used exec on process substitution but not on command substitution. I actually kind of remember wanting to tell that using `exec` on `$(exec route)` after it was changed that it would not make a difference but I just skipped it.

Comment: @konsolebox - you're an bash guru here. :) As I told, here is nothing wrong with the exec in command substition too ...

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, there is no good way to count the number of files in a directory in the standard POSIX shell (probably because POSIX does not standardize any aspect of the file system). The only portable way is to count them one by one:

```
count=0
for f in $data_dir/*_1.data; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && count=$((count + 1))
done

if [ "$count" -eq 1 ]; then
...
fi
```

If you want, you can break out of the for loop early. If you care that there is at least one file, break as soon as `count` reaches 1. If you care that there is exactly one file, break as soon as `count` exceeds 1.

Most suggestions to use `find` rely on the `-printf` extension to output a string guaranteed to be free of any whitespace. All other methods are susceptible to whitespace (or at least newlines) in a potential file name to skew the counting.